# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch... JPA+postgresql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, bytecode-manipulation

I'm struggling with error which I constantly receive while launching method returning some objects from server to ExtJs. 
I'm totally new in JavaEE and I suppose I've made mistakes somewhere.

Here's the log from JBossDevStudio console:

```
11:04:37,217 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-20) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SimpleApp/rest/person: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 18
Exception Details:
Location:
entity/Person._persistence_isAttributeFetched(Ljava/lang/String;)Z @4: ifnull
Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
0000000: 2ab4 005f c600 0e2a b400 5f2b b600 bd99
0000010: 0007 04a7 0004 03ac                    

at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 18
Exception Details:
Location:
entity/Person._persistence_isAttributeFetched(Ljava/lang/String;)Z @4: ifnull
Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
0000000: 2ab4 005f c600 0e2a b400 5f2b b600 bd99
0000010: 0007 04a7 0004 03ac                    

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:88) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.convertClassNamesToClasses(ClassDescriptor.java:1214) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.convertClassNamesToClasses(Project.java:362) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:322) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:151) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:207) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:195) [eclipselink.jar:2.0.2.v20100323-r6872]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:177) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.getEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:82) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:130) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at main.Controller.getPeople(Controller.java:38) [classes:]
at main.Controller.personSort(Controller.java:48) [classes:]
at main.Controller$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.personSort(Unknown Source) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
... 31 more
```

When I click on column label on grid in ExtJS I fire method on the server which should ask database for records, sort them using parameters which I provide and return back to client . Firstly, I would like to call getPeople() method without any crash, later I'll think about the rest. Communication between ExtJS and server works fine.
Here are my implemented classes and persistence.xml:

Controller:

```
package main;

import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import entity.IPersonDao;
import entity.Person;


  @Path("/")

public class Controller {

@Inject
RestService helloService;

@Inject
IPersonDao personDAO;

@GET
@Path("/person")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public List<Person> personSort(@QueryParam("page") int page,@QueryParam("start") int start,@QueryParam("limit") int limit,@QueryParam("sort") SortParamList sort)
{
    List<Person> people=personDAO.getPeople(); //after that instruction everything crashes
    //return Response.ok("Ok",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    return people;
}
```

}

Person:

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="People")
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    protected String Imie;
    protected String Nazwisko;
    protected String Pesel;

    @Inject
    public Person()
    {}

    public Person(String imie,String nazwisko,String pesel)
    {
        this.Imie=imie;
        this.Nazwisko=nazwisko;
        this.Pesel=pesel;

    }

    public String getImie() {
        return Imie;
    }

    public void setImie(String imie) {
        Imie = imie;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return Nazwisko;
    }

    public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
        Nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    public String getPesel() {
        return Pesel;
    }

    public void setPesel(String pesel) {
        Pesel = pesel;
    }



}
```

IPersonDao:

```
package entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface IPersonDao {

    public abstract List<Person> getPeople();

}
```

PersonDao:

```
package entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;


@Stateful
public class PersonDAO implements IPersonDao {

//  @PersistenceContext(unitName="SimpleApp")
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    //public void Persist(Person person){ ???!?!?!!? O_o
    //  em.persist(person);
    //}
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see entity.IPersonDao#getPeople()
     */

    public List<Person> getPeople(){
        TypedQuery<Person> query=em.createQuery("Select p FROM Person p Order by p.Id",Person.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
       <persistence-unit name="SimpleApp" transaction-type="JTA">
             <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
             <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/sampleDS</jta-data-source>

             <class>entity.Person</class>
              <properties>
                    <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sampleDB"/>
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
                    <!--property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/ -->
                    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                    <!--property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /-->
                    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/db_init.sql"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>

             </properties>
       </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I tried many combinantions with @Inject or PersistenContext.
I tried UseSplitVerifier option and nothing worked.

Comment: stackmap frame problems are usually related to which JDK is being used, and what JDK some java bytecode was written for (JDK 1.7 introduced some things that were defaulted in earlier JDKs). And your situation is? Particularly wrt the method Person._persistence_isAttributeFetched ... where was that created?

Comment: I don't understand clearly what are you telling me about method Person._persistence_isAttributeFetched. Idid't write it. I'm using JDK 1.8

Comment: somebody wrote it and YOUR ERROR MESSAGE complains about it, so the way to work out the problem is DEBUG that method and where it comes from. Bytecode enhancement process somewhere in what you're using? Which JPA implementation?

Comment: No. I've set this project from scratch. I want to learn Java EE in practice and I can swear nobody else was involved in this project. It's as simple as possible application just for my purposes. The version of JPA is 2.1

Comment: I asked what is the JPA *implementation*, not the version number. That method is created somewhere ... by you, or by some automatic process, so work out where

Comment: It's hibernate implementation. I'm telling you one more time. I didn't write such a method. I gave you the implementation of Person class. If this method isn't there I have no idea where it could be.

Comment: So Hibernate added it for you. An error message doesn't appear for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a problem with REST communication between ExtJs client and JavaEE server. I've set new Dynamic project and put persistence.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="y" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/sampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>entity.Person</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sampleDB" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />    
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've also put in wildfly configuration this datasource:

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/sampleDS" pool-name="sampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sampleDB</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>admin</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

The rest wast just a copy/paste operation from one project to another. Everything is working fine at the moment. However I can't explain the source of the problem.